# Torn visa in my passport

Tags: visas, passports

Back in April 2017, I applied for a student visa at the Israeli Embassy. My passport came back, as you can see, in this torn condition. I questioned them at the time about my passport's validity and they said it's okay.

Since then I have travelled to Nepal, Czech RepublUc, Ukraine and Israel with no problem whatsoever. I even transitded through Abu Dhabi, Moscow and Latvia without a problem. This visa expired and I applied for a new one in Israel, which I received with no problem.so far i have not recieved any problems. Do i need to apply for a new passport or this is fine?  Are there any officials on here or someone in the field that could answer? No opinions please

[image]

Comment: This picture shows the old visa, right? You have a new visa that is in good condition?

Comment: I'd have applied for a new passport without delay, but you seem to have had no trouble. Should you applying for a new one now? That's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Nobody cared about this, not even Israel who caused the damage! I think you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: I fail to find a question here